# Mobile dev: solve screen glare?

Tags: mobile, screen, user-experience

I am noticing a lot of possible applications of mobile software is limited due to screen glare from the sun. What are ways a software developer or UI designer can mitigate this, and what are the fundamental hardware problems that need to be addresses and who is working on them?

It is a compounded question, but this is a compounded problem!

Insight appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The higher the contrast in your image, the less of a problem it will be. Beyond that, tough cookie.

The fundamental hardware problem is that surfaces which aren't shiny are translucent or otherwise blurry.

You can manipulate the [refractive index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index) but there are trade-offs. Cost, propensity to crack/smudge/scratch/tarnish, etc.

Thinking laterally, if you write a scary videogame, people will want to play it in the dark :-)